# Display child elements in a single row unless they overflow, then display a single column

Tags: html, css

I have n elements containing a small amount of text that I want to display in a fixed-width container as one row like so:

[image: Single row]

However, when all the inner text elements cannot fit in a single row, I want them appear in a single column:

[image]

I don't want to use inline-blocks so that there will be multiple rows, and a dynamic number of elements per row:

[image]

And I don't want the elements to be split across n columns depending on the size. It should be one row, or one column if that doesn't fit.

Can this be done with just CSS? Perhaps using flexbox or grid layout?

Comment: Can you post some code (HTML, CSS) with your question?

Comment: Sure, here's the inline-block version to play around with, if that helps: https://codepen.io/ScriptSmith/pen/ExaBXVx

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible with just CSS. With JS, we could make it work.

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: There is no CSS method of detecting overflow

Comment: Since your text elements has no explicit max-width I think it is not possible to make it work with a CSS only solution.

Comment: How would it work if there's a max width?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is not possible without JavaScript (because you need it to detect overflow). With that being said, you could base your solution around `flexbox` as it allows you to switch between row / column layout via single CSS property on your container element. Other option might be to switch between `inline-block` / `block` display on the children for example, but you would have to do that for all of them - that's why `flexbox` is better here. Example might look like this:

```js
const outer = document.querySelector('.outer')

if (outer.clientWidth < outer.scrollWidth) {
  outer.classList.add('direction-column');
} else {
  outer.classList.add('direction-row');
}
```

```css
.outer {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.inner {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: none;
}

.direction-row {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.direction-column {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">Some text, blah</div>
  <div class="inner">Some text, blah blah</div>
  <div class="inner">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="inner">Some text, blah blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="inner">Some text, blah blah blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="inner">Some text, blah blah blah blah blah blah</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I find this question interesting. One possible solution is using *Media Query*, but only if you know the **exact** width at which the `.outer` container will break the layout of your `.inner` classes. If the text won’t change dynamically, then you can easily calculate the width. In that case, you might use:

```css
    .inner {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 877px) {
      .inner {
        display: block;
      }
    }

    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #222;
      font-family: monospace;
    }

    .outer {

      padding: 0 10px;
      width: fit-content;
    }

    .inner {
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      margin: 10px 0;
      background-color: darkgrey;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="outer">
    <p>
      <span class="inner">blah blah</span>
      <span class="inner">blah blah blah</span>
      <span class="inner">blah blah blah blah</span>
      <span class="inner">blah blah blah blah blah</span>
      <span class="inner">blah blah blah blah blah blah</span>
    </p>
  </div>
```

It is an unusual workaround but it is *CSS* only.

Comment: How would you calculate width without using JS ? If you would want to do that manually, don't forget that you need to consider font size, letter spacing, and what is the biggest problem - that each letter has different width actually. (iiiii vs ddddd - see?). Then, if you would want to apply this pattern on different places with different texts (or the same texts with just slightly different styles), you would have to manually calculate and hardcode things again there.

Comment: Thanks for the creative solution. I have to agree that unless you know *exactly* what the conditions are on the client and the dimensions of the text elements, it's not the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

As have already been said there is no `CSS` method of detecting overflow.

**Dynamic solution**

So we can make texts container `display: flex` with `flex-wrap: wrap;` and with `javascript` look on window resize if the last element `offset` `top` of text elements is bigger that first element's. And in this case modify texts container to `flex-direction: column;`

Look `jquery` and `javascript` versions in snippets in full page mode and resize the window.

**Jquery version**

```js
$(function() {
  detectWrap();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  detectWrap();
});

function detectWrap() {
  $(".container").each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("direction-column");

    if ($(this).children().first().offset().top < $(this).children().last().offset().top) {
      $(this).addClass("direction-column");
    }

  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.text-element {
  background-color: #A9A9A9;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}

.direction-column {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript version**

```js
window.onload = function(event) {
  detectWrap();
};

window.onresize = function(event) {
  detectWrap();
};

function detectWrap() {
  const container = document.getElementsByClassName("container");

  for (let i = 0; i < container.length; i++) {
    container[i].classList.remove("direction-column");

    const firstText = container[i].firstElementChild;
    const lastText = container[i].lastElementChild;

    if (firstText.offsetTop < lastText.offsetTop) {
      container[i].classList.add("direction-column");
    }
  }

}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.text-element {
  background-color: #A9A9A9;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}

.direction-column {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="text-element">Some text, blah blah blah</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The only way I know of to do that easily is by using the Bootstrap framework in your HTML.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/[Bootstrap Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/)

```
<!--You put this in your <head> section:-->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!--Put something like this in the body:-->

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
          One of three columns
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          One of three columns
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          One of three columns
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```